# rename all files in linux with one go

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
Fedora 18
3.10.12-100.fc18.x86_64
```

Hello,

I have many files like the ones below. I would like to rename them by removing the -unknown-linux-gnu part. so `libpjsip-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a` would be `libpjsip-x86_64.a`

I tried doing the following but failed, substitute for an empty space:

```
rename 's/-unknown-linux-gnu//' *.a
```

It failed with a message `rename: not enough arguments`

```
libg7221codec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a        
libpjsip-ua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a
libgsmcodec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a          
libpjsip-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a
libilbccodec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a         
libpjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a
libmilenage-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: You are not invoking `rename` with the correct number of args. Why don't you `man rename`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *.a
do
    mv $i ${i/-unknown-linux-gnu/}
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename):

```
rename "-unknown-linux-gnu" "" *-unknown-linux-gnu*
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `mmv`

```
$ mmv -v "*-unknown-linux-gnu*" "#1#2"
libpjsip-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a -> libpjsip-x86_64.a : done
```

The `*` on the first argument are recalled with the `#1` in the second argument of `mmv` so it's quite easy to build something like you want with it.